# How do I prevent access to domain subfolders when hosting two domains using the same webspace?

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have two domains that point to the same root folder of my webspace. My root directory is setup like so:

- /domain1
- /domain2
- /shared

Where requests to...

- http://www.domain1.com/* should do an internal redirect to http://www.domain1.com/domain1/*
- http://www.domain2.com/* should do an internal redirect to http://www.domain2.com/domain2/*
- http://www.domain1.com/shared/* or http://www.domain2.com/shared/* should not be redirected and should server from the /shared folder

#### Current .htaccess:

```
# Redirect domain1.com paths to domain1 folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain1/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain1/$1

# Redirect controllers to index.php.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^domain1/(.*)$ /domain1/index.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]

# Redirect domain2.com paths to domain2 folder.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domain2/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domain2/$1

# Redirect controllers to index.php.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^domain2/(.*)$ /domain2/index.php?controller=$1 [QSA,L]
```

What's remaining to do is:

1. Don't serve pages from http://www.domain1.com/domain1 if the user
   types this in manually.
2. Don't serve pages from http://www.domain1.com/domain2 if the user types this in manually (I've already implemented this but omitted it for brevity).

*Note: I would rather not use symlinks since I run xampp on windows for local development.*

#### My question is:

How can I redirect internally from http://www.domain1.com to http://www.domain1.com/domain1 but not serve http://www.domain1.com/domain1 if it is typed in by the user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to test the [request line](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec5.html#sec5.1) to see what URI has originally been requested:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /(domain1|domain2)[/?\ ]
RewriteRule ^(domain1|domain2)($|/) -
```

In this case you can send the status code 404 (`[R=404]` flag, since Apache 2) or rewrite the request to some point where such requests are handled.